# Admin Bar items active only on plugin page

Tags: admin-bar

Am looking to use the admin-bar to house the title of our plugin and links for options and admin pages of our plugin. This includes removing current links and nodes held on the admin bar.

No issues in removing and adding these items, however we need it to be conditional to the plugin pages only. Have tried -

```
     if($post->post_type == 'profile'){
```

and

```
if ( is_singular( 'profile' ) ) {
```

Neither of these have achieved what we are after. It should also be mentioned that the plugin is setup as a custom-post-type.

Thank you for your help

Comment: This is the code for adding the title to our admin bar - if you can help me make this singular to the post type then we should be able to take care of the rest '/* Add Title */

add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'add_toolbar_items', 100);
function add_toolbar_items($admin_bar){

 $admin_bar->add_menu( array(
  'id'    => 'main-title',
  'title' => 'Targeting',
 ));
 
}'

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

```
function add_toolbar_items($admin_bar){
if('profile' == get_post_type())
$admin_bar->add_menu( array(
    'id'    => 'main-title',
    'title' => 'Targeting',
));
```

}
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'add_toolbar_items', 100);